# Foundation/compass - app.css does not update

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

It was working a few hours ago, but now when I make changes to `_settings.scss` it does not update `app.css` even though it says in compass watch `modified scss/_settings.scss write css/app.css`.

I tried the solution with changing

```
find line 12: SASS @if (index($modules, $name) == false) {
replace with line: SASS @if(not index($modules, $name)) {
```

no luck.

sass 3.3.14

compass 1.0.1